# One dimensional inverse square law - motion of charged particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, charge

I'm working on a simple case of two oppositely charged, equal-mass particles in a 1-dimensional system. It might as well be an electron and positron, but without the case of annihilation on contact. The actual system is two magnetic domain walls of opposite magnetic charge (think south and north pole) in a ferromagnetic nanowire.

I situate one particle at x = 0 and it remains fixed there. The second particle starts at x = $+x_0$ with some velocity $v_0$ directed away from the first particle in the positive x-direction.

The second particle feels an attractive Coulombic force from the first particle, proportional to some constant $k * 1/x^2$. I would like an equation of motion for the position $s$ of the second particle at a given time $t$.

My current attempt is:
$s = v_0*t + 1/2 (k/m * 1/s^2)*t^2$

Due to the $1/s^2$ term on the RHS I'm having trouble finding a usable solution, any help much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I would recommend: 1/ enclose to latex formating for readibility 2/ as you fix part.#1  this can be translated to the central Coulomb field problem

Comment: I also dont understand how do you want to connect your magnetic field and 1D system

Answer (score 1):

> I would like an equation of motion for the position $s$ of the second particle at a given time $t$.

In general, you won't be able to find such an expression in the elementary functions. What you can do find is an equation for the time $t$ at which the second particle has a position $s$: $t=t(s)$. This comes in three flavors, one for energy $E=\frac 1 2 mv^2 - \frac k s$ being negative, another for energy equal to zero, and the third for energy being positive. The special case of $E=0$ is reversible (i.e., you can find an expression for $s(t)$  The expressions for non-zero energy are transcendental. You can use numerical methods to solve for this, similar to how one solves the Kepler equation for an orbiting object. In fact, this is the radial Kepler problem.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you started with assumes that the acceleration is constant as the particle moves, which is not the case. You would need to start with $F=ma$ and solve with a variable force in an ugly second-order differential equation:
$$\frac{k}{x^2} = m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}.$$

Luckily, the Coulomb force is conservative, meaning you can associate a potential energy to it. This means you can skip one integration and start with the first-order conservation of energy equation.
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 - \frac{k}{x} = E_0$$
where $m$ is the mass of the moving particle, $v$ is its velocity, $k$ is a constant equal to Coulomb's constant times the product of the electric charges of the particles, $x$ is the moving particle's position, and $E_0$ is the particles initial energy given by the initial conditions of the problem:
$$E_0 = \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 - \frac{k}{x_0}.$$

Substituting $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$
$$\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 - \frac{k}{x} = E_0.$$
Unfortunately, [the result of integrating this is not solvable](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2Fsqrt%5BA%20%2B%20B%2Fx%5D) for $x(t)$. This means the dynamics of the problem have to be worked out numerically.

Comment: That should be $k/x$ rather than $k/x^2$ in your expression for the potential energy. Besides, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You're right, I thought the result of the integral seemed too simple.